# Pick random samples from a array in python

Tags: python, database, random

I have got two datasets `new_train_db1` (with size 3000x200) and `new_train_db2` (with size 3000x200) and the correspondant labels `train_labels` (3000x1). I want to subsample `new_train_db1`, `new_train_db2` and `train_labels` and keeping just 100 samples. I have the following code:

```
np.random.seed(0)
reduced_train_db1 = new_train_db1[np.random.randint(new_train_db1.shape[0], size=100), :]
np.random.seed(0)
reduced_train_db2 = new_train_db2[np.random.randint(new_train_db2.shape[0], size=100), :]
np.random.seed(0)
reduced_labels = train_labels[np.random.randint(train_labels.shape[0], size=100)]
```

Actually, what i want is to keep the same samples every time that I run the code. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `np.randon.randint` three times so obviously the result is going to be different everytime. Why not just run it once and reuse the same indices everywhere.

You can define a do a one time operation in which you generate random indices using the `numpy.random.randint` function and store it in a file and write a few additional lines wherein you read this file and use it for selecting the same rows on every run. You can get the indices using -

```
ind = np.random.randint(3000,size = (100,))
```

You can save and load the array using `numpy.save` and `numpy.load`.

If you intend on using same rows only during one session and don't necessarily want them to be same across all your sessions, you don't have to save and load as well.

Comment: Are you sure that the my three arrays using different indexes?